# RVM version of Ruby is different from Ruby -v

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, rvm

I'm trying to install the paperclip gem but I'm being prompted that it requires Ruby version >=1.9.2

When I check my version on RVM , I get 1.9.3, Whereas when I check it via the ruby -v command, I get 1.8.7 How do I get my rails application to use the latest version of RUby instead?

```
@ubuntu:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a basic step you can set the default ruby rvm is to use as follows.

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

You can also set it at the project level by adding an `.rvmrc` file with the following contents to your project root directory. You should commit this to the repo.

```
rvm 1.9.3
```

As a final measure, you should stop using rvm and switch to [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/). It's much better, and we need to stop overriding cd.

Comment: the real problem might be in not using ruby, are you by chance overwriting PATH in any of *rc files?